# How do I call the default method of an inherited abstract class?

Tags: matlab, oop

I want to set up class indexing operations when using parentheses, but first I want to understand how to call the default method from an inherited class:

```
classdef Test < matlab.mixin.indexing.RedefinesParen

    properties
        Property1
    end

    methods (Access=protected)
        function varargout = parenReference(obj, indexOp)
            varargout = parenReference@matlab.mixin.indexing.RedefinesParen(obj, indexOp);
        end
    end
end
```

When trying to call the first element

```
T = Test()
T(1)
```

Outputs the following error:
*Method 'parenReference' is not defined for class 'matlab.mixin.indexing.RedefinesParen' or is removed from MATLAB's search path.*

As I understand it, I can't access the method or it doesn't have an implementation in the inherited class, but if you don't override the indexing operation of the class, everything works.

I have been familiarizing myself with the documentation:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/forwarding-indexing-operations.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.indexing.redefinesparen-class.html

Comment: According to the documentation you linked, `parenReference` is an abstract method in `matlab.mixin.indexing.RedefinesParen`. So you can't call it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I implement (or call) the default behavior of a function, as it happens in Matlab?

Comment: By not inheriting from `RedefinesParen`.

Comment: I want to change the behavior of the class when calling `T(i)` so that such a call is redirected to a function, while the rest of the behavior remains as intended.So that my change doesn't affect the call `T.Property1(i)`.

Comment: OK, so define `parenReference` and the other few methods to do what you need them to do. I don’t see the problem. This is supposed to be the easy way of changing the workings of the parenthesis operator. Feel free to do it the old-fashioned way by overloading [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html), like I have always done.

Comment: Note that this base class changes `T(…)` but not `T.…` nor `T{…}`. `subsref` handles all three, so there you do need to call the default behavior with `builtin` where needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is exactly why I didn't want to use `subsref`, since it also affects the behavior of `T.…`, but using `builtin` may solve the problem. Tell me how to write a default call using `built` in for all class properties. Or does it need to be prescribed for each property separately?

Comment: All of that stuff can be found in the documentation, just search for it. The documentation is really good. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html